# Make a predicate in setupFetchedResultsController using a different entity from defined

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

```
       +-----------+           +-----------+         +-----------+
       |   -Dia-   |           | -Autobus- |         | -Parada-  |
       +-----------+          +-------------+        +-----------+
       |  nombre   |          |Relationships|        |  nombre   |
      +-------------+         +-------------+       +-------------+ 
      |Relationships|   ------>|   dia     |        |Relationships| 
      +-------------+   |      +-----------+        +-------------+ 
       |  byDia    |<---|      |  parada   |<------->|  byParada |
       +-----------+           +-----------+         +-----------+
```

I want to fetch data in the Entity "Parada" based on the relation of "Autobus" and "Dia".

For Ex:

```
 Autobus 1 has Dia=2 and Parada=4
 Autobus 2 has Dia=3 and Parada=5
 Autobus 3 has Dia=2 and Parada=7
```

So i'm trying to get a list of Paradas that match with any Day.

For Ex:

```
Fetch Paradas with Dia 2 ----> Parada 4 and Parada 7
```

Here's the code i'm trying to fix:

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{

    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Parada"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"RolePickerTVCell is Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    // Here's the problem:

    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nombre = myString.text"];


    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"nombre"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

    NSLog(@"The following roles were fetched for the Picker by RolePickerTVCell:");
    for (Parada *fetchedRole in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
        NSLog(@"Role: %@", fetchedRole.nombre);
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in IOS and Objective-C development so any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display only objects for a given day, use a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"byParada.dia.nombre = @%", theDay]
```

The precise answer depends on what type the "nombre" attribute has (Integer, String),
and whether the selected day (`theDay`) is given as `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `int`...

Comment: Even I changed the predicateWithFormat a little ( "byParada.dia.nombre contains[cd] 'TheDay'" ) I must say THANK YOU VERY MUCH I fix this damm problem at least!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nombre = %@ AND byParada.dia.nombre = %@",@([myString.text intValue]),@(2)];
```

As your predicate.

It will fetch ass `Parada`s with a given `nomber` and `Autobus.dia` of 2